# Какова история слов антиквар, антикварий, антиквариат, антик?

Tags: этимология, лексика

Из современной литературы:

— И как ты себя называешь? **Антиквар?** — Уж скорее ***антикварщик***. Скромнее надо быть...

Но слово **антикварщик** не обнаруживается, зато был **антикварий**:

Один **антикварий** в Праге, Иоанн Керновский, владеет ковром, который будто бы принадлежал Магомету. [«Раннее утро», 1913]

А еще в этимологическом словаре указан **антиквариус** ― в Табели о рангах название одного из низших придворных чинов.

Теперь же остались только ***антиквар*** и ***антиквариат***, причем не очень понятно, как слово ***антиквариат*** образовалось (мотивирующее слово и значение суффикса).

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

1) Да, ведь есть еще ***антик***. Итак, антиквариат и антик, антикварий, антиквар и "антикварщик". Видно, не хватает в языке одного слова для того, чтобы выразить два значения: знаток антиквариата и его продавец.

**АНТИКВАРИАТ**, -а; м. собир. Антикварные вещи (книги, картины, украшения и т.п.). Торговля антиквариатом. Собирать а.

**АНТИК,** [от лат. antiquus ― древний]. Устар. 1.  Сохранившийся памятник античного искусства; старинное или редкое художественное изделие. 2. О человеке с необычными или устарелыми привычками, взглядами.

И слово ***антик*** в значении "памятник искусства" не очень-то устарело, вернулось к нам, и теперь надо различать ***антиквариат*** и ***антик***:

― Какая прелесть, **настоящий антик!** ― похвалила Мария, оглаживая высокое горло керамической вазы...[Вацлав Михальский. Одинокому везде пустыня (2003)]

2) А в этимологических словарях **слова с этим корнем не разбираются**, даже у Черных ничего нет, даже в книге "Античные корни в русском языке" по поводу ***античный*** ничего не сказано, зато везде есть ***anti*** ― против.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Интересный и неожиданно сложный вопрос. Я не смогу дать полный ответ, но поделюсь тем, что нашёл. Поиск в имеющихся у меня этимологических словарях ничего не дал. Вот что нашлось в энциклопедии 1862 г. издания (включаю в ответ, поскольку требуется не только этимология, но и история термина.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Этимологическую справку приводит викисловарь. К сожалению, не удалось найти первоисточника этой справки, но звучит она вполне правдоподобно (и согласуется с en-wiktionary).

> Происходит от лат. antiquarius «касающийся древности», далее из
>   antiquus «древний, старинный», далее из ante «перед, впереди; раньше,
>   прежде», далее из праиндоевр. *anti «против, напротив». В ряде слав.
>   языков слово заимств. через нем. Antiquar.

Заимствованный суффикс **-ат** в этом слове в некоторых источниках объясняется не собирательным значением, а примерно следующим образом:

> Термины-существительные со значением «носитель процессуального
>   признака». 
>  Суффикс  **-ат**. Термины с этим суффиксом обозначают
>   предмет (одуш. и неодуш.), являющийся объектом действия или
>   возникающий в результате действия, названного мотивирующим словом:
>   
>  1) лицо: *делегат*,  *депутат* и др.; 
>  2)  неодуш. предмет:
>   **антиквариат**, *аттестат, дубликат,* и др.

Comment: *Я не смогу дать полный ответ* - а что вам мешает считать ваш ответ полным? Я даже и не знаю, что тут добавить-то по существу вопроса. Что касается первоисточника этимологической справки, то её смело можно принять как самодостаточную. Мы же не занимаемся этимологией слов в **немецком** (или каком еще, кроме русского)  языке.

Comment: @Мимоходов Спасибо! Когда я это говорил (про неполный ответ), я никак не мог разобраться со словообразованием слова **антиквариат**. На тот момент у меня была другая версия, но она меня не устраивала. Последнюю часть я добавил позднее (а сам ответ уже не правил).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, очень интересно, но, к сожалению, вопросов (после Вашего ответа и  подробного рассмотрения темы) теперь еще прибавилось. Я их обозначила в дополнении.